# python: iterate a specific range in a list

Tags: python, iteration

Lets say I have a list:

```
listOfStuff =([a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [f,g])
```

What I want to do is to iterate through the middle 2 components in a way similar to the following code:

```
for item in listOfStuff(range(2,3))
   print item
```

The end result should be as below:

```
[c,d]
[e,f]
```

This code currently does not work, but I hope you can understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
listOfStuff =([a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [f,g])

for item in listOfStuff[1:3]:
    print item
```

You have to iterate over a slice of your tuple. The `1` is the first element you need and `3` (actually 2+1) is the first element you don't need.

Elements in a list are numerated from 0:

```
listOfStuff =([a,b], [c,d], [e,f], [f,g])
               0      1      2      3
```

`[1:3]` takes elements 1 and 2.

Comment: So if I wanted to go from the second item to the next to last item in the list I would do for item in listOfStuff[1:len(listOfStuff)]

Comment: @ccwhite1: No, you would rather do `listOfStuff[1:len(listOfStuff)- 1]` or just `listOfStuff[1: -1]`. BTW, do you care to elaborate what was your main reason to use `range` in your question? Thanks

Comment: @eat: no, `listOfStuff[1:-1]` ignores the last element. @ccwhite1: use `listOfStuff[1:]`

Comment: no, `listOfStuff[1:len(listOfStuff)- 1]` and `listOfStuff[1: -1]` will both give the same elements (ignoring first and last, as what ccwhite1 IMHO just asked). Thanks

Comment: I hope listOfStuff[1:3] is not evaluated at every step of the array.

Answer (score 10):

A more memory efficient way to iterate over a slice of a list would be to use `islice()` from the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import islice

listOfStuff = (['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f'], ['g','h'])

for item in islice(listOfStuff, 1, 3):
    print(item)

# ['c', 'd']
# ['e', 'f']
```

However, this can be relatively inefficient in terms of performance if the start value of the range is a large value since `islice` would have to iterate over the first start value-1 items before returning items.

Comment: WARNING: Can be *extremely* inefficient. For example, `islice(list1, 100000, 100100)` will *first* iterate over the first 99,999 values (just wont return them). Try it yourself with cProfile; its also in the docs.

Comment: @Jeff: Point taken...and answer updated accordingly. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: how to make islice more efficient?

Comment: @MhmdAdmn: Not possible, generally speaking.

Comment: thanks for responding! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

You want to use slicing.

```
for item in listOfStuff[1:3]:
    print item
```

Comment: Ouch, I never get slicing indices wrong, and when I tested it in the command line I was too hurried and thought I got the correct results when they weren't. I'll edit it in and test more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 3):

By using `iter` builtin:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
# i is the first item.
i = iter(l)
next(i)
for d in i:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using built-in *slice*.

The syntax is:
slice(start,stop,step)

A little complicating when print out.

print(yourlist[slice_code])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).