# Python : Deleting next items based on sum of previous item in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I've three sample input lists of tuples:

```
bc_lst = [(639, 16), (653, 25), (734, 33), (768, 50), (777, 16), (827, 42), (854, 24), (867, 63), (869, 48), (877, 26), (903, 26), (927, 26), (929, 22), (949, 20), (969, 20), (990, 19), (999, 23), (1010, 19), (1030, 20), (1042, 63), (1049, 20), (1069, 17), (1143, 18), (1158, 18), (1174, 25)]

uc_lst = [(1215, 25), (1293, 25), (1317, 29), (1327, 43), (1346, 26), (1374, 26), (1400, 21), (1420, 21), (1430, 102), (1443, 20), (1465, 19), (1486, 20), (1506, 21), (1528, 20), (1549, 20), (1570, 20), (1591, 20), (1612, 16), (1621, 26), (1632, 21), (1639, 26), (1653, 21)]

dt_lst = [(1566, 39), (1609, 24), (1620, 20), (1650, 38), (1658, 20), (1691, 37), (1701, 20), (1732, 38), (1772, 16), (1785, 19), (1814, 36), (1854, 37), (1854, 38), (1861, 19)]
```

and a buffer variable `buf = 5`. I want to do this operation on `bc_lst`, `uc_lst` and `dt_lst` : check from the first item, if the sum of the tuple is less than the sum of the first element of the next tuple and the buffer then remove the next item from the list and check for the next list item.

Consider `bc_lst`. Sum of first tuple is `655` and `653+5 > 655`, so we keep `(653,25)`. Now check whether `734 +5 > 653+25`, which is `True` so keep the `(734,33)`. Now check `768 +5 > 734+33`, which is again `True`, so we check for the next item but `777 +5 > 768+50` is `False`, so we drop the tuple `(777,16)`. Now we again check if `827+5 > 768+50` which is `True`, so we keep `(827,42)`. The process goes on.

This is the code I tried :

```
def func1(a1):
    count = 0
    while count < len(a1)-1:
        if a1[count+1][0] + buf < sum(a1[count]):
            del a1[count+1]
        count +=1
func1(bc_lst)
```

The output I get for bc_lst is :

```
[(639, 16), (653, 25), (734, 33), (768, 50), (827, 42), (867, 63), (877, 26), (903, 26), (927, 26), (949, 20), (969, 20), (990, 19), (1010, 19), (1030, 20), (1049, 20), (1069, 17), (1143, 18), (1158, 18), (1174, 25)]
```

, for uc_lst the output is :

```
[(1215, 25), (1293, 25), (1317, 29), (1346, 26), (1374, 26), (1400, 21), (1420, 21), (1443, 20), (1465, 19), (1486, 20), (1506, 21), (1528, 20), (1549, 20), (1570, 20), (1591, 20), (1612, 16), (1632, 21), (1653, 21)]
```

, for the dt_lst the output is :

```
[(1566, 39), (1609, 24), (1650, 38), (1691, 37), (1732, 38), (1772, 16), (1785, 19), (1814, 36), (1854, 37), (1861, 19)]
```

Whereas, the desired output for `bc_lst` is :

```
[(639, 16), (653, 25), (734, 33), (768, 50), (827, 42), (867, 63), (927, 26), (949, 20), (969, 20), (990, 19), (1010, 19), (1030, 20), (1049, 20), (1069, 17), (1143, 18), (1158, 18), (1174, 25)]
```

, the desired output for `uc_lst` is same as the output I get and the desired output for `dt_lst` is :

```
[(1566, 39), (1609, 24), (1650, 38), (1691, 37), (1732, 38), (1772, 16), (1814, 36), (1854, 37)]
```

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python doesnt remove all the items from a list while iterating over the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846323/python-doesnt-remove-all-the-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list)

Comment: `itertools.compress` is probably what you want here

Comment: @Aemyl It's not duplicate, the logic behind removing the items from the list while iterating over the list is different for my question.

Comment: `itertools.compress` should still work here. Should I write an example as an answer?

Comment: Ok, I guess Mike Robins has answered this question well and shown that `itertools` is not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that if you remove an item, you don't want to increment count.

```
buf=5

def func1(a1):
    count = 0
    while count < len(a1) - 1:
        if a1[count + 1][0] + buf < sum(a1[count]):
            del a1[count + 1]
        else:
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To save intermediate results you can process elements one by one.

For example, you will have a function with input as a list you want to process, buffer, and current processing element index like this:

```
def process_list_element(list, current_index, buffer):
    if list[current_index + 1][0] + buf < sum(list[current_index]):
        del list[current_index+ 1]
    else:
        current_index += 1
    return list, current_index
```

* Please look carefully as it's just pseudocode to demonstrate the approach

And then just repeat

```
index = 0
buffer = 5
while index < len(list) -1:
    list, index = process_list_element(list, index, buffer)
```