# Why do two loop methods return the correct result the first time, but the third method takes three runs achieve the right result?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, division

I'm struggling to understand why my Python script is giving me identical answers for the first two methods I have, but for the third method I have to run the process at least 3 times to get the correct answer.

I understand that my first method may be the most efficient, but I'm trying to understand *why* the third method doesn't achieve the same result the first time.

Code is posted below, thank you!

```
# Sanity check - Modular [remainder] divison in loops
# Python Libraries 
from random import randint
# Create a list of 50 random integers between 0 and 1000
randomNumbers = []
for i in range(100): 
    randomInt = randint(0, 1000) 
    randomNumbers.append(randomInt)
print("List of 50 values: ", randomNumbers,"\n") 

##########################################################
# METHOD 1: Remove odd numbers - New list based
newList     = [x for x in randomNumbers if x % 2 == 0]
print('List comprehension method...')
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(newList)))
print(newList)
print('\n')

# METHOD 2: Keep even numbers - Loop Based
evenList = []
for i in randomNumbers:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        evenList.append(i)
print("List append method...")
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenList)))
print(evenList)
print('\n')

# METHOD 3: Remove odd numbers - Loop Based
counter     = 0
# > Loop 1
for i in randomNumbers: 
    if i % 2 != 0:
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))
print(randomNumbers)
# > Loop 2
for i in randomNumbers: 
    if i % 2 != 0:
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))
print(randomNumbers)
# > Loop 3
for i in randomNumbers: 
    if i % 2 != 0:
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))
print(randomNumbers)
# > Loop 4
for i in randomNumbers: 
    if i % 2 != 0:
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))
print(randomNumbers)
```

Comment: Suggested a duplicate, because you are modifying the array whilst you are iterating over it, your code will never touch every item in the list as you iterate through it, the fact it's working by the 3rd attempt is just luck.  [Python doesn't remove all the items from a list while iterating over the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846323/python-doesnt-remove-all-the-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
for i in randomNumbers: 
    if i % 2 != 0:
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
```

Once you do a `remove` for example against element 9, you have effectively reduced the size of the list by 1 and renumbered all subsequent elements. Even after 3 iterations you won't even end up with the same elements as in the first two methods. If you are going to do this by removing elements, then remove in reverse order:

```
for i in range(len(randomNumbers) - 1, -1, -1):
    if randomNumbers[i] % 2 != 0:
        del randomNumbers[i]
```